# How to link Office 365 calendars to Exchange resource calendars?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, exchange

For one of the Projects, I have a request to link Exchange Calendars to Office 365. I have no idea how this can be accomplished. Do I have to create calendars in SharePoint online first? If yes, how do I then link these newly created calendars to the Exchange resource calendar?

Can someone please help me with steps here please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood your question correctly, but I'll try.

If the Exchange calendars are shared calendars, then you could be able to add them to an office 365 outlook calendar, by clicking the option "Add calendar" and link them from a specific location.

Alternatively, if you have outlook client installed, you could use the "Open Calendar" option in the Calendar view and pretty much do the same.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Deepu. Potentially its a migration project I am working on and client has some exchange calendars which they wanted to connect to sharepoint, is this possible or those can only be connected via outlook?